# Javascript nested callbacks in for loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, callback

I have nested functions which should not block the I/O.

```
 for(let i = 1; i < category_amount;i++){
        pool.query('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM threads_mphp WHERE category = ?',i,function(error, results1, fields) {
            console.log(i);
            pool.query('UPDATE category SET posts=? where category=?',[results1[0]['COUNT(1)'],i],function() {
                console.log(i);
            });
        });
    }
```

Both queries work with the same index i.
I cannot use let for such purposes.
The console.logs doesn't output as expected two same numbers in a row.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: *" I cannot use let for such purposes"*: why not? *"The console.logs doesn't output as expected two same numbers in a row"*: why did you expect that? That would be expected when it was *synchronous* code, but it is asynchronous. It is quite likely that the outer `console.log` all execute before all the inner ones. Why is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is an issue here. The callback function (`function(error, results1, fields)...`) and subsequent UPDATE statement is invoked only when the results of `pool.query`is completed. As a result, the logs may appear out of order since you are spawning the `pool.query` calls as fast it will allow you in the loop.

Add a logging statement before `pool.query`to see exactly what is happening.
I believe the logging will look something like

```
1 query! - called from loop
2 query! - called from loop
3 query! - called from loop
1 SELECT finished! - 1st callback is invoked and UPDATE dispatched.
4 query! - loop is still running!
2 SELECT finished!
1 UPDATE finished!
3 SELECT finished!
2 UPDATE finished!
...
```

```
for(let i = 1; i < category_amount;i++){
        console.log(`${i} query!`);
        pool.query('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM threads_mphp WHERE category = ?',i,function(error, results1, fields) {
            console.log(`${i} SELECT finished`);
            pool.query('UPDATE category SET posts=? where category=?',[results1[0]['COUNT(1)'],i],function() {
                console.log(`${i} UPDATE finished`);
            });
        });
    }
```